# Embeddings of lens spaces in complex projective plane $\Bbb CP^2$

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Is it possible to embed a lens space $L(p,q)$ (smoothly or topologically) into the complex projective plane $\Bbb CP^2$? According to this note  https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/aissa/slides/candidacy.pdf, it is impossible to embed $L(p,q)$ with $p>1$ in $S^4$. So I am curious about the same problem with $S^4$ replaced by $\Bbb CP^2$, or blow-ups $\Bbb CP^2\sharp n\overline{\Bbb CP^2}$ of $\Bbb CP^2$. Any comments or references will be thankful!

Comment: Just a bit information. There is a smooth embedding in $n$ copies of the $\Bbb CP^2$ for some positive integer $n$. [see this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.01260.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some lens spaces embed in $\mathbb{C} P^2$ and some don't and the question of exactly which lens spaces embed in $\mathbb{C} P^2$ is open for both smooth and topological embeddings. However, some restrictions are known.

The easiest obstruction to embedding in $\mathbb{C} P^2$ is the following. If a lens space $L$ embeds smoothly (resp. topologically) into $\mathbb{C} P^2$, then $L$ bounds a smooth (resp. topological) rational homology ball. This is because the image of $L$ separates $\mathbb{C} P^2$ into two components. Applying the Mayer-Vietoris sequence with rational coefficients shows that one of these components is a rational homology ball.

I don't have much to add about topological embeddings other than to note that the above obstruction implies that the lens space $L(p,q)$ can only embed topologically in $\mathbb{C} P^2$ only if $p$ is a square.

If one is interested in smooth embeddings into $\mathbb{C} P^2$, then the work of [Lisca](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701610) which classifies which lens spaces bound smooth rational homology balls. This gives a list of lens spaces which can potentially be embedded in $\mathbb{C} P^2$. However, not every lens space on Lisca's list embeds in
$\mathbb{C} P^2$. For example, Brendan Owens has an obstruction based on Donaldson's diagonalization theorem that can obstruct these embeddings. See for example Example 3.4 of [this paper](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/%7Ebowens/papers/nonsympballs.pdf). His paper also provides some examples of lens spaces which do embed smoothly into $\mathbb{C} P^2$.